# What is the proper endpoint for connecting to azure container service swarm cluster from c# https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-container-service

After deploying a azuze container service and using swarm, how do one connect using the example given:

```
var credentials = new CertificateCredentials (new X509Certificate2 ("CertFile", "Password"));
var config = new DockerClientConfiguration("http://ubuntu-docker.cloudapp.net:4243", credentials);
DockerClient client = config.CreateClient();
```

I have made the certificate and just cant figure out wht the proper endpoint to use is?

the url from azure portl: `<name>-mgmt.<region>.cloudapp.azure.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACS does not use certs by default. We use SSH tunneling as documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect

If you have connected to the masters and manually configured it to use certs as well as correctly installing those certs o the masters then there is nothing magical about the endpoints and connection details. It's just Docker, so follow the appropriate Docker documentation. The correct URL is, as you note in your question `<name>-mgmt.<region>.cloudapp.azure.com`.

However, you should be aware that since we do not use certs by default we do not open the necessary ports on the Master LB. You will also need to open those on your master LB. For an example (which is against the agent LB but the processes is the same) see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-enable-public-access

Comment: Thanks ross, I just came to this same conclussion. Took me abit of time to figure out what to google. I am looking into what the proper path would be from here to allow me to securely talking with my cluster from c#. DOCKER_OPTS='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock' is not tht secure :D but works